# How to move UIButton up on button click

Tags: iphone, ios7

I would like to move my UIButton on clicking it....its just basically like animating it. When clicking on the button it should move up from its current position and should move down on clicking another button. since Im totally a newbie to iOS please someone help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: There are no `UIButton`s in Xcode since Xcode is not written using UIKit but with AppKit. Did you mean to move a button in **your iOS app?**

Comment: yes i did mean the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way...

```
-(IBAction)btn_press:(id)sender{
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 700, 665, 601); //your initial frame
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                     animations:^{
                         btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 103, 665, 601); // Final Frame
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I just tried the above code and i replaced the btn with my button name and it showed "use of undeclared identifier". pls help

Comment: my method name is PostTraffic and error shows "use of undeclared identifier postTraffic".

Comment: im not able post a screen shot..:(

Comment: just declare the your button PostTraffic in .h file.

Comment: I didn't actually....by mistake i had clicked it twice...too bad internet problem...:(

Answer (score 0):

In Button target method,change button frame to change position.

```
-(void)btnAction:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
CGRect newFrame = <Frame to change position>

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[btn setFrame:newFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: what value should i replace instead of <Frame to change position>..??

Comment: new frame to move up button position. Suppose Button frame(10,10,30,30) then new frame will be (10,0,30,30). Change of y position makes button to move up

Comment: same error shows up here...in place of "mybutton" i replaced it with my button name and still shows use of undeclared identifier. I've tried other operations with the same button and it just works fine.

Comment: i have updated my answer to converting sender to button.Plz try this